# jira's plugin code from 6.3.15 to 7.2.2 has some problems

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

Is there any document about how to coding in jira 7.2.2?

I wrote a plugin code about jira in the version of 6.3.15. I used the code as follows:

```
private CustomFieldManager customFieldManager = ManagerFactory.getCustomFieldManager();
private WorkflowManager workflowManager = ManagerFactory.getWorkflowManager();
```

and they were compiled successfully and worked well.

But when I turned the jira from 6.3.15 to 7.2.2, I found the class had no attribute named `getCustomFieldManager` and `getCustomFieldManager`.I also can not find any document about jira 7.2.2. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

In JIRA 7.0 a bunch of methods of ManagerFactory have been removed. You should now use ComponentAccessor instead.

The [JIRA 7.0 - API changes](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/latest-updates/preparing-for-jira-7-0/jira-7-0-api-changes#JIRA7.0-APIchanges-ApiCleanup) page mentions:

> **Removal of accessor methods for ManagerFactory and ComponentManager classes**
>
> The ManagerFactory and ComponentManager classes have been deprecated for some time. These classes were not intended to be part of the API, and in JIRA 7.0, the accessor methods for these classes will be removed.
>
> Historically, add-ons have used these classes to get to JIRA components statically. If your add-on uses these classes, you should inject your components via the constructor injection instead. If this is not possible or practical, the ComponentAccessor class provides the supported way to access components statically.

For every new JIRA version, Atlassian maintains a *Preparing for JIRA x.y* page that provides links to all the platform and API changes.

You can start with the [Preparing for JIRA 7.0](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/latest-updates/preparing-for-jira-7-0) page.